# systemd niceness and scheduling configurations not effective in processes performance

Tags: centos, performance, scheduling

My team inherited the care and maintenance of code for a service that runs three python scripts and creates processes which play a part in sending data from our product to another product. One process converts files our product makes from one type to another, another zips X number of them and a third SFTPs them to another machine.
Both our product and the inherited service run on CentOS 7.

We've noticed some performance hits since we've implemented this product. I'm tasked with trying to lower the service's occurrence and to make sure it only runs when CPU consumption is low so that during peak activity our main product will have all the resources it needs.
I tried playing with the .service file for this serviceת adding the following parameters under "[Service]" and running a performance test automation to try and see any effect after every step:

1. Nice=19
2. Nice=19 + adding "chrt -p 0; nice; ionice" to the path to the bin at ExecStart
3. Nice=19 + CPUSchedulingPolicy=batch
4. Nice=19 +  CPUSchedulingPolicy=batch + IOSchedulingClass=best-effort + IOSchedulingPriority=7
5. Nice=19 + CPUSchedulingPolicy=batch + IOSchedulingClass=idle + IOSchedulingPriority=7
6. Nice=19 + CPUSchedulingPolicy=idle + IOSchedulingClass=idle + IOSchedulingPriority=7

After each change, before running the performance test automation, I ran `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart <application>.service`.

I haven't seen any significant change in the performance test results - not from the average test results from the last two months and not when comparing results of the tests themselves. I feel like I'm not fully configuring things properly. What am I missing?

The service's .service file I edited is at `/etc/systemd/system/` and I ran `systemctl enable <application>.service` and then `systemctl list-unit-files` to make sure the file was there and marked as enabled.

Comment: How are you measuring performance, and what do you see and what do you expect to see?

Comment: @jsbillings Our product listens to events on databases and analyzes them. The performance test connects to databases and generates traffic there and the automation checks how many queries were sent to the databases vs. how many were analyzed by our product. 
The average TPS for our product is 45K while the performance testing done during my experiments yielded TPS of 23K